# How to query items in Current Iteration with Azure DevOps analytics views?

Tags: azure-devops, analytics

I'm trying to create an analytics view with Azure DevOps in order to get items in the current iteration.

I've tried using the @CurrentIteration as a parameter but that doesn't work when creating the analytic view because @CurrentIteration is not a valid path:

[image]

I've also tried filtering by iteration start and end dates but @Today is not being accepted as a parameter either.

Does anybody know how this could be achieved?